# customize wpf grid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell

I have 2 tables with a relationship between them.
I am trying to display the content of the parent table in a datagrid in such way that one of the datagrid cells to be expandable, being able to display the content of the child table.
What is the(best) way to achieve this? I assume the little black arrow (cell expand) is part of the datagrid control and it shouldn't be designed in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WpfToolkit datagrid has a feature called [Row Details](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx#rowdetails).  You can design a UI for the related table in the template.  You can also specify that the details be shown always, on selection, or controlled manually.